# How can I connect an Aux input to a 2004 Honda Jazz stock stereo?

Tags: honda, audio

Just bought a used Honda Jazz 1.4 SE for my wife, and although it has a CD/Radio with an Aux button on it, there is no external connection I can see.

As she wants to be able to connect her iPod, I am looking at how to do this.

My background is in electronics so I'm more than happy to build circuitry if required, but am hoping I can just wire a headphone type plug into the stereo if possible.

Is there a socket I can get at, and if so does anyone have a wiring diagram?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing recently on a 94 Accord (different radio harness). Just looked around again to see if there's a solution on the 03-07 Honda radios and here are the results:

On some units you can solder into the aux interface. Otherwise you can cheat the radio into using its CD/Nav/XM expansion plug as an aux input. This usually requires an additional [part](http://www.oemautosound.com/pc-289-88-pie-hon03-aux-honda-2003-2011-auxiliary-input-adapter.aspx) to convince the radio you're using an expansion, but my guess is that part is just shorting a few pins, so you could probably whip out your background in electronics and save the $.

Anyway [I recommend starting here](http://www.hondafitjazz.com/audio.htm) and/or googling "honda fit jazz head unit wiring diagrams." As a last resort, the radio accessories work. 20-60 USD, easier than hacking but audio quality is not great.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On some models, the aux socket (3.5mm stereo) is next to the cigarette lighter under a flap. Took me ages to find too.

Comment: Sadly on this model there is no AUX connection, but I managed to wire one up as per the guidance on @Tyler's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A variety of manufacturers sell a small transmiter that plays your ipod thru your radio.See if this model will work for you.[enter link description here](http://salestores.com/maxell191213.html)