# How can I connect an Aux input to a 2004/5 Honda Jazz stock stereo?

Tags: honda, jazz

As a follow up to a question on getting phone to connect to the aux input of a Honda Jazz 2005. [How can I connect an Aux input to a 2004 Honda Jazz stock stereo?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/how-can-i-connect-an-aux-input-to-a-2004-honda-jazz-stock-stereo/39024#39024)

I have exactly the same plug as discribed in the referenced post on my jazz. There are a couple of additional ones though, blue (occupied), white (free), green (free), black (antenna). WHat I would prefer to have it to be able to plugin some kind of mass storage capability that would also function as the mp3 interface. But, I like simple ideas like the one you have left above! Where would I be able to buy the plug for the green socket? I have spend quite a bit of time looking around for adapters (my preferred solution), but, I am never sure if it will work in mine. Could someone also tell what the white socket is for? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The unused plugs are typically used for other options like GPS or Multi-Disc CD changer, etc. It all depends how your car was optioned. I could not find any vehicle specific information about your car. Might be that I am in a different region than you.

I am fairly sure you cannot just plug in a mass storage device (hard drive or thumb drive) and expect the stereo to read it. If you you are referring to an MP3 player or iPod, that can be done with an auxiliary jack.

To connect an iPod or cell phone headphone jack, you need to enable the AUX input on the stereo using the green connector. This will allow you to be able to add a 3.5mm input. This YouTube video, [Activating and connecting the AUX on a 2005 Honda Jazz (EU Model)](https://youtu.be/ZE0hKMuIoSc)  has detailed instructions how to do it.